# Another way of writing an if statement?

Tags: javascript

It may sound a bit stupid, but is there a shorter way of writing the following if statement in less words :

```
if(auxiliars.environment == "Development") {
    less.env = "development";
    less.watch();
}
```

Because I have that statement as part of a function :

```
set_environment: function(environment) {
    if(auxiliars.environment == "Development") {
        less.env = "development";
        less.watch();
    }
}
```

And I was wondering if I can somehow return that two lines of code :

```
less.env = "development";
less.watch();
```

The main reason I'm asking is because in PHP I'm doing something like the following :

```
return (!empty($len)) ? hash('sha512', str_pad($stream, (strlen($stream) + $len), substr(hash('sha512', $stream), $this->round(strlen($stream) / 3, 0), ($len - strlen($stream))), STR_PAD_BOTH)) : hash('sha512', substr($stream, $this->round(strlen($stream) / 3, 0), 16));
```

And I was wondering if I can do something similar in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes you can. Using exactly the same syntax. Have you tried? That said, the PHP code is quite unreadable. A classic `if else` would have been welcome IMO.

Comment: You could use commas to combine two statements into one, but... Ew. Refactor the two statements into a method, or leave it as-is. IMO since there's no "else" using a ternary seems... odd.

Comment: Oh, that's great. I'm not a JavaScript expert, so I prefer asking first and getting some insight before barging in :) But my concern is how would I return two statements, because returning a single value is simple, I'm not sure how to do it for two or more if it's the case

Comment: @DaveNewton I see, but there will be an else statement too, I'm working on it, but I wanted to be sure I can do something like that before doing it

Comment: @Roland Please don't, though--essentially unreadable unless there's refactoring. Let an actual obfuscator do the obfuscation--the *source* should strive to be readable, not as short as possible.

Comment: @DaveNewton - I get your point, my source should be as readable as possible, there's plenty of compilers that can shorten my expressions, but I wanted to see if that's possible in JavaScript too and to try it :)

Comment: Code is more often read than written. Go for readability, not for short code. Your conditional operator example is very hard to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys, I appreciate it. So basically I should go for organized and readable code rather than shorthand versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really, why would you want? Your if statement is clean and easily to understand.

Yet, you might try the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
auxiliars.environment == "Development"
   ? ( less.env = "development", less.watch() )
   : void 0;
```

But using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) doesn't make your code better.

Comment: You have to put those two expressions in parens - the comma operator is otherwise evaluated last. This: `( less.env = "development", less.watch() )`. In its current state, your code is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has the ? : statement, if that's what you are asking.

So

```
var x = 5;
var y = (x < 10) ? "bar" : "foo";
```

will assign the string "bar" to y.

Comment: You're not teaching anything there. He already knows the syntax.

Comment: @sp00m Not in JS, apparently, which is what I thought the question was asking.

Comment: Really? It did not seem like he was aware that that syntax worked in JS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)